# How can have an instance or a return type of a generic type conforming to a protocol with associated value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift-protocols

So I don't know if the title gets my problem right but here is the thing:

I have an enum for identifying several types of table view cells. Every type of cell has its own class. I have conformed every one of those to a protocol but with an associated type. I am now trying to create a way to have instances of those classes and use their protocol methods and properties arbitrarily. Here's an example:

```
enum CellType {
    case a, b, c
   
    func getCellClass() -> ProtocolWithAssociatedType.Type { //Error here
        switch self {
        case .a: return ClassA.self
        case .b: return ClassB.self
        case .c: return ClassC.self
    }
}
```

This enum raises an error of `Protocol 'CreateOrderTableViewCellProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` on that line.

So this is the exact protocol I have except the name:

```
protocol ProtocolWithAssociatedType: UITableViewCell {
    associatedtype Delegate
    var delegate: Delegate? {get set}
    func setupCell()
}
```

All the classes ClassA, ClassB and ClassC conforms to this. They all have their own delegate protocols which they cast with `typealias` e.g.:

```
protocol ClassADelegate: class {
...
}

class ClassA: UITableViewCell, ProtocolWithAssociatedType {
    typealias Delegate = ClassADelegate
    weak var delegate: ClassADelegate?
    func setupCell() {}

    ...
}

extension ViewController: ClassADelegate {
...
}
```

All of these is to slim down the tableView(...cellForItemAt:...) and other similar methods since there are many cell classes in this project and it's beyond the point of being readable and it's really really hard to make any development on this particular view controller because of this.
I have an extension for UITableView for creating reusable cells for those which it's reusable id is the same as it's class' name like this:

```
func dequeueReusableCell<C>(_ cellType: C.Type, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> C where C: UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = String(describing: cellType)
        
    guard let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as? C else {
        fatalError("Failed to find cell with identifier \"\(identifier)\" of type \"\(C.self)\"")
    }
        return cell
}
```

So I am willing to use this like following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellType = CellDataArray[indexPath.row].cellType
    let cellClass = cellType.getCellClass()

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(cellClass, for: indexPath) \\ Here I have to have the cell conform to the protocol somehow

    cell.delegate = self \\So here is the associated type which doesn't need to be read but is need to be written only
    cell.setupCell() \\Obviously there are going to be some data passed to the cell instance right here
    return cell
}
```

I have read so many questions and answers and I am trying every one of them to accomplish this yet I haven't been able to do so. I am trying to avoid massive functions in the view controller and make things as modifiable as possible. All those cells are acting like little view controllers themselves and they all have to communicate with the view controller. Also the cells are not static, like for different occasions there are different cells I have to show. Right now even adding one simple cell is a hell of a work, let alone creating a whole new occasion. But with this approach I am trying to make things... modular.

So is there any way I can do this without having a runtime crash here and there or creating a blackhole and bringing the universe to an end?

EDIT: I have tried the generic type way but unable to do so. Because of the way I want the `func getCellClass()` work, it is not possible to make the complier know what that generic type will be. Like following:

```
func getCellClass<C>() -> C.Type where C: ProtocolWithAssociatedValue {
...
}
```

So even I force cast the return values to the `C.Type` then I have problem where I call it simply because C is not known.

**EDIT**

I have removed the associated value from the protocol and did the following:

```
protocol ProtocolWithAssociatedType: UITableViewCell {
    var _delegate: AnyObject? {get set}
    func setupCell()
}
```

```
protocol ClassADelegate: class {
...
}

class ClassA: UITableViewCell, ProtocolWithAssociatedType {
    weak var _delegate: AnyObject? { didSet { delegate = _delegate as? ClassADelegate } }
    private weak var delegate: ClassADelegate?
    func setupCell() {}

    ...
}

extension ViewController: ClassADelegate {
...
}
```

This way the protocol is usable as return type of that enum function and I can force cast the reusable cell to it since the protocol itself conforms to UITableViewCell. I have built without any problem yet can not test yet (test servers are down outside of working hours). When I test it and if it runs without any problem, I will post it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

So after a couple of days' work and trial-error I have finally came up with a solution. Thanks to @Cristik I have had an insight and changed my approach.

Firstly I have changed my way of handling the delegates. I had a different delegate for every cell. Now I have only one which all of those cells use.

So this way I was able to make my property like following:

```
protocol CellProtocol: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate: CommonCellDelegate?
    func setupCell(...)
}
```

For all the properties and some common methods of the view controller which the cells will use I have declared the delegate protocol like following:

```
protocol CommonCellDelegate: class {
    var viewControllerProperty1: SomeClass1 { get set }
    var viewControllerProperty2: SomeClass2 { get set }
    ...
    var viewControllerPropertyN: SomeClassN { get set }

    func someCommonFunction1(...) -> ...
    func someCommonFunction2(...) -> ...
    ...
    func someCommonFunctionN(...) -> ...
}
```

As my intention from the beginning being to keep the view controller nice and clean, I have put those uncommon methods which cells individually need down below those cells' class declarations as an extension to the delegate property:

```
class SomeCellClass: CellProtocol {
    var delegate: CommonCellDelegate?
    func setupCell(...) {
    ...
    }

    ...
}
extension CommonCellDelegate {
    func someMethodForTheCellAbove1(...) -> ... {
    ...
    }
    func someMethodForTheCellAbove2(...) -> ... {
    ...
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

As I didn't need the enum method to return different classes anymore, I have changed it a bit to return the reuse id of every cell type. So no need to return the class type there:

```
enum CellType {
    case cellA, cellB, cellC, ...
   
    func getCellClass() -> String { //Error here
        switch self {
        case .cellA: return String(describing: ClassA.self)
        case .cellB: return String(describing: ClassB.self)
        case .cellC: return String(describing: ClassC.self)
        ...
        // Note: We use the the name of the cell classes as their reuse id's for simplicity.
    }
}
```

And finally, I was able to create those cells in the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method quite easily and without creating a rip in the fabric of the space-time:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellType = CellDataArray[indexPath.row].cellType
    let cellReuseId = String(describing: cellType.getCellId())

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseId, for: indexPath) as? CellProtocol else { fatalError("some fatal error") }

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.setupCell(...)
    return cell
}
```

This way it's very very easy to make new implementations since all that needs to be done is to create the class, make the class conform to the `CellProtocol`, make a case for it in the enum, add the case to the array whereever or whenever it's needed, register the cell id and **voilà!** It's there! And because all the needed properties needed are now known by the cell thanks to the delegate, they can easily use those like their own properties, only difference is that it's not `self.something` but `delegate?.something`.

I hope this effort of mine might be helpful to others. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're trying to mix polymorphic behaviour (i.e. the array of cell types) with static behaviour (protocols with associated types), and this is more or less not possible with the current Swift design.

Protocols with associated types are determined at compile time, while the code in your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method is executed at runtime, and this makes it somewhat incompatible with protocols with associated types.

```swift
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(cellClass, for: indexPath)
```

In the above code you need to be able to tell the compiler which type do you expect for the cell, in order to inject the delegate, however that's a compile-time feature, and you need it at runtime, hence the incompatibility.

I'm afraid you'll have to stick to runtime error propagation/handling for this. Unless you are willing to change the `delegate` to match the whole set of possible delegates, and in this case the associated type is no longer needed, which enables the runtime features.

```swift
protocol MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate: CellDelegate1 & CellDelegate2 ... & CellDelegateN { get set }

    func setupCell(SomeCommonProtocolThatGetsCastedAtRuntime)
}
```

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer. It didn't solve my problem but it gave me an insight of how to solve it.